# JS filter does not work properly. Does not know why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Have a look on my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371390/how-to-show-no-record-found-meassage-in-table-filter)

**What is Problem with my filter?**

Implemented my filter but it's not working properly on some specific values and does not show *No Record Found* message. Like if I select 70 and 0 in earning and scoring it works fine and shows No Record Found message. But when I select 200 and 0 in earning and scoring respectively, it does not show No Record Found message. I'm unable to figure out the problem.

```js
$("#filter").click(function () {
  var tdScoring,tdEarning,hidden_rows=0;
  var scoring=$("#scoring1").val();
  var earning = $("#earning1").val();
  
  table = document.getElementById("mastermindTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var rows=tr.length;
    rows-=2;

 for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
   tdScoring = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
   tdEarning = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
   if (tdScoring || tdEarning) {
   if (tdScoring.innerHTML==scoring ) {
    }
    if (tdScoring.innerHTML.indexOf(scoring) == -1 || tdEarning.innerHTML.indexOf(earning) ==-1) {
      ++hidden_rows;
    }
  }
}
if(hidden_rows==rows){
  for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
      document.getElementById('noRecordTR').style.display = "";
}

else
{
  document.getElementById('noRecordTR').style.display = "none";
  for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
   tdScoring = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
   tdEarning = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];

   if (tdScoring || tdEarning) {
    if (tdScoring.innerHTML.indexOf(scoring) == 0 && tdEarning.innerHTML.indexOf(earning) == 0) {
      tr[i].style.display = ""; 
    }
    else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 p0">
              <div class="fixed-table-toolbar">
                <div class="bars pull-left">
                  <div id="toolbar">
 <select class="form-control input_billing" id="earning1">
                      <option value="">Earning</option>
                      <option value="70">70</option>                                     
                      <option value="200">200</option>
                      <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bars pull-left">
                  <div id="toolbar">
<select class="form-control input_billing" id="scoring1">
                        <option value="">Scoring</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="120">120</option>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
</select>
                  </div>
                </div>
<button id="filter" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:8px;" type="button">Filter</button>
              </div>
            </div>
<table class="table table-condensed" id="mastermindTable">
  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="18%" align="left">Name</th>
                    <th width="26%" align="left">Email </th>
                    <th width="20%" align="left">Expertise</th>
                    <th width="16%" align="left">Earning</th>
                    <th width="16%" align="left">Scoring</th>
                    <th width="4%" align="left">Status</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="mastermindTableBody">
                <tr id="noRecordTR" style="display:none"> 
                      <td></td>
                      <td>No Record Found</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                     <td></td>                    
                  </tr>
                    <tr> 
                      <td>Ronald</td>
                      <td>ronald@gmail.com</td>
                      <td>PHP</td>
                      <td>70</td>
                      <td>12</td>
                     <td>Active</td>                    
                  </tr>
                  <tr> 
                      <td>Arsnel</td>
                      <td>ars@gmail.com</td>
                      <td>Larave</td>
                      <td>200</td>
                      <td>120</td>
                     <td>Active</td>                    
                  </tr>
                  <tr> 
                      <td>Abeera</td>
                      <td>abr@gmail.com</td>
                      <td>CI</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                     <td>InActive</td>                    
                  </tr>
                  <tr> 
                      <td>Abeera</td>
                      <td>abr@gmail.com</td>
                      <td>CI</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0</td>
                     <td>InActive</td>                    
                  </tr>
                 
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I not only want a solution but most importantly I want to know why my code is not working as it should be. Please anybody explain it thoroughly.

Comment: Because `"200".indexOf("200") == -1 || "120".indexOf("0") == -1` returns false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is Problem with your Code:**

To understand problem, we must first know how IndexOf method works.

**1-String.prototype.IndexOf():**
The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.
[https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf](http://jsfiddle.net/mobensarwar/1j4nhby7/51/)

**2-Array.prototype.indexOf():**
The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
[https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf][2]

And your code falls in the 1st definition because you are applying IndexOf method on a string(may be you're unaware about it).
So when you select 200 earning and 0 scoring and hit filter button there is no value match in the first row and value of hidden_rows updated to 1.
And at 2nd row value of earning exactly matches so indexOf method returns 0 for earning but when filter search for scoring ,taking 120 as a string ,he founds that there is 0 on 2nd index(starting from 0) of 120, so indexOf  method returns 2 for scoring. And so exact value does not found but your condition becomes false and variable hidden_rows did not update.

```
 if (tdEarning.innerHTML.indexOf(earning) ==-1 || 
 tdScoring.innerHTML.indexOf(scoring) 
 == -1) {
  ++hidden_rows;
 }
```

Remember that indexOf method only returns -1, when value does not found on any index of a string. And if number of supplied characters is equal to the number of calling string characters, indexof() method considers whole string is at 0 index.

**Solution:**

The simplest way to resolve this issue is to use Array.prototype.indexOf():
Get value of scoring and earning from each tr in your forloop and save them in an array and then apply indexOf() on them.

```
  tdEarning[0]='';
  tdScoring[0]='';
  for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
  tdEarning[1] = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].innerText;
  tdScoring[1] = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4].innerText;
  if (tdScoring.indexOf(scoring) >-1 && tdEarning.indexOf(earning) >-1) {
  tr[i].style.display = '';  
  }
  else {
  tr[i].style.display = 'none';
  ++hidden_rows;
  }
  }
```

[Jsfiddle Demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mobensarwar/1j4nhby7/51/)

Comment: @AmmarKhan i also have removed un necessary code from your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with:

```
if (tdScoring.innerHTML.indexOf(scoring) == -1 || tdEarning.innerHTML.indexOf(earning) ==-1) {
  ++hidden_rows;
}
```

Basically, in your code, you're checking if the earnings/scoring appears in one of the table row cells.

Eg: Does "0" appear in "120"? Yes, it does.

So instead, you need to check equality (eg: does "0" equal "120"? No, it doesn't). You can do this by using this code instead:

```
if (tdScoring.innerHTML.trim() != scoring || tdEarning.innerHTML.trim() != earning) {
  ++hidden_rows;
}
```

I also advise that you use the trim function for `.innerHTML` to remove whitespace around the string as a precautionary measure.

See working examle below:

```js
$("#filter").click(function() {
  var tdScoring, tdEarning, hidden_rows = 0;
  var scoring = $("#scoring1").val();
  var earning = $("#earning1").val();

  table = document.getElementById("mastermindTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var rows = tr.length;
  rows -= 2;

  for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
    tdScoring = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
    tdEarning = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (tdScoring || tdEarning) {
      if (tdScoring.innerHTML != scoring || tdEarning.innerHTML != earning) {
        ++hidden_rows;
      }
    }
  }
  if (hidden_rows == rows) {
    for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById('noRecordTR').style.display = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('noRecordTR').style.display = "none";
    for (i = 2; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tdScoring = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
      tdEarning = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];

      if (tdScoring || tdEarning) {
        if (tdScoring.innerHTML.indexOf(scoring) == 0 && tdEarning.innerHTML.indexOf(earning) == 0) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 p0">
  <div class="fixed-table-toolbar">
    <div class="bars pull-left">
      <div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control input_billing" id="earning1">
          <option value="">Earning</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="200">200</option>
          <option value="0">0</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bars pull-left">
      <div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control input_billing" id="scoring1">
          <option value="">Scoring</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="120">120</option>
          <option value="0">0</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="filter" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:8px;" type="button">Filter</button>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-condensed" id="mastermindTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="18%" align="left">Name</th>
      <th width="26%" align="left">Email </th>
      <th width="20%" align="left">Expertise</th>
      <th width="16%" align="left">Earning</th>
      <th width="16%" align="left">Scoring</th>
      <th width="4%" align="left">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="mastermindTableBody">
    <tr id="noRecordTR" style="display:none">
      <td></td>
      <td>No Record Found</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ronald</td>
      <td>ronald@gmail.com</td>
      <td>PHP</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Arsnel</td>
      <td>ars@gmail.com</td>
      <td>Larave</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>120</td>
      <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Abeera</td>
      <td>abr@gmail.com</td>
      <td>CI</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>InActive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Abeera</td>
      <td>abr@gmail.com</td>
      <td>CI</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>InActive</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Might be wise to `trim()` the values obtained from `innerHTML`.

Comment: Good idea! Updated my answer

Comment: @NickParsons your solution is not working if there is no value selected in earning and scoring.